# How can I root a Samsung Galaxy Note Pro (4.4 Kitkat) using Mac OS X (10.9 Mavericks)?

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, samsung, odin, macos

I've looked around for instructions on rooting a Samsung Galaxy Note Pro, but I've only found instructions for Windows computers. It seems that the Samsung ODIN ROM flashing tool is only available for Windows, as far as I can tell. Can anyone help me do this on a Mac? I'm comfortable with mucking around a lot (I'm a software developer) so don't worry if your solution isn't a simple 1-click thing, as long as it works on Mac OS X and a Samsung Galaxy Note Pro running Android 4.4 Kitkat.

Comment: If all you need for the process is Odin (I'm not familiar with it), then you could look at the cross-platform implementation, [Heimdall](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/).